# Approach for adding favorites tab

Tags: iphone

Which approach is best to adding into favorites tab.

I need to add all my events which are in array. calling from web service. 
two ways i can add to favorites...

1. adding into local...

USing nsuserdefaults...encoding and decoding......

or i can depend on web-service... create a web service. for favorites and fetch data from web service. when i click add favoirtes button.. it send device id and event id to web - service and created respective event in web service.. where i can fetch data from web service.

i got two ways approach which is best.

Can any one help me out.

@thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a good example without knowing more about what you'll be storing as "favourites", but as a general approach you should store the data locally so that's it's accessible if the internet/remote server is not available.

However, if the data is of value outside the application (or needs to be synced with other devices, etc.) the application should periodically communicate with the remote server to sync the favourites data.

In other words, you should (potentially) use a mix of both approaches.

**UPDATE**

In terms of saving data on the device itself, you might want to take a look at the [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and indeed Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) - this will tell you everything you need to know about serialising data and subsequently storing it.

Comment: Can any one help me out saving data .... i mean example for saving data in iphone.

Comment: @kiran - I've updated my answer with some pointers regarding serialising and saving data - hope this helps. :-)

Comment: @kiran - There's nearly always sample code linked to within Apple's class reference documentation - check the "Related sample code" section at the top of the document. :-)